# What is the best runs strategy to burn fat

Tags: burn-fat

i want to burn some extra fat on my body and im a bit confused should i do jogging for long distance or do multiple sprints as more as i can ?

Comment: We've had several topics about burning fat in the past, the bottom line is that consuming less energy than you expend will result in weight loss (which includes fat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Calories burnt during exercise:**

- Running 7 mph (11.2 km/h) for an hour (a 155 lbs or 70 kg person): 809 Calories ([Wisconsin.gov](https://www.dhs.wisconsin.gov/publications/p4/p40109.pdf))
- Sprinting for 10 minutes (no more details revealed): 800 Calories ([EurekAlert](https://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2012-10/aps-moh101112.php))

Anyway, the simplest tactic to lose excessive body fat is to **consume less calories than you spend.** This can help you **decrease appetite:**

- Avoid carbohydrates that are quickly absorbed: sugary foods (cola, fruit juices, sweets, deserts) and foods with plain starch (potatoes, white rice, white pasta)
- Avoid foods made mainly from fat + carbs (chocolate, chips)
- Eat foods high in fiber, such as whole grain bread or other cereals and low-calorie vegetables

Comment: Thanks,  so i guess sprinting is more effective

Comment: 10 minutes of sprinting would require 20 sprints x 30 seconds, for example, with some rest in between. So, it's up to you what you find more convenient. It doesn't seem to be easier to me than running for an hour at 11 km/h.

Answer (score 0):

it depends upon your current physical condition.  If you are at the verge of obese, your heart is the first muscle you should begin conditioning! lots of interval marching. The same is true if your a sedentary with some fat beginning to develop.    if you are active, and have a few thick spots, progressive plyometrics can ramp off fat fairly quickly.    yes, sprints.     Jogging, is a test for, or the maintenance of, a healthy heart. Goal of to feel capable of a short marathon.